# How to specify size of the square when drawing in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I have a beamer frame as shown below. The problem is when I draw nodes `A` and `B` how can I specify their size? I want both of them to be squares of side length `1.5cm`, and the text to be centered inside the square.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Tables
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    overlay-beamer-styles,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Obf}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node[draw] (A) {$C$};
\node[draw, right=3cm of A] (B) {$\mathsf{Obf}(C)$};
\node[above=1cm of A] (C) {$x$};
\node[below=1cm of A] (D) {$C(x)$};
\node[above=1cm of B] (E) {$x$};
\node[below=1cm of B] (F) {$C(x)$};
    \draw[->] (C)--(A);
    \draw[->] (A)--(D);
    \draw[->] (E)--(B);
    \draw[->] (B)--(F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you don't need `\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}`, beamer already loads them for you and if your tex distribution is reasonable up-to-date, you also don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the option `minimum size=1.5cm` like this:

```
\node[draw, minimum size=1.5cm] (A) {$C$};
\node[draw, right=3cm of A, minimum size=1.5cm] (B) {$\mathsf{Obf}(C)$};
```

[image: Two nodes with text and arrows]